# Validating inputed month based on current year using jquery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 select elements.One for month and one for year. (Lets assume validating credit card expiry).

So I want to validate the the month if the inputted month is not less than the current month.

HTML CODE:

```
<select class="custom-control form-control" name="auto_aim_expDateMonth" id="expDateMonth_7" style="width:50px">
        <option value="1">01</option>
        <option value="2" >02</option>
        <option value="3" >03</option>
        <option value="4" >04</option>
        <option value="5" >05</option>
        <option value="6" >06</option>
        <option value="7" >07</option>
        <option value="8" >08</option>
        <option value="9" >09</option>
        <option value="10" >10</option>
        <option value="11" >11</option>
        <option value="12" >12</option>
    </select>
        <select class="custom-control form-control" name="auto_aim_expDateYear" id="expDateYear_7" style="width:80px">
            <option value="2020" >2020</option>
            <option value="2021" >2021</option>
            <option value="2022" >2022</option>
            <option value="2023" >2023</option>
            <option value="2024" >2024</option>
            <option value="2025" >2025</option>
            <option value="2026" >2026</option>
            <option value="2027" >2027</option>
            <option value="2028" >2028</option>
            <option value="2029" >2029</option>
        </select>
```

Jquery Code :

```
            var now= new Date();
            var month=now.getMonth();
            var year1=now.getFullYear();

                $("#shippingadd").validate({
                rules: {
                    auto_aim_expDateMonth:  {
                        monthCheck: month,
                    },          
                    auto_aim_expDateYear:  {
                        minStrict: year1,
                    },          
                },
                messages: {
                    auto_aim_expDateMonth: {
                        monthCheck: "",
                    },
                    auto_aim_expDateYear: {
                        minStrict: "",
                    },
                },
            });
            $.validator.addMethod('minStrict', function (value, el, param) {
                return value >= param;
            });
            $.validator.addMethod('monthCheck', function (value, el, param) {
                //code logic here
            });
```

The Logic might check first the current year if its like 2020 than it needs to check the month element (as i have asked this question in 2020). If the year is not 2020 than month element should not be validated.

Comment: You have the basic framework laid out, but I see that you've made absolutely no attempt at writing the `monthCheck` logic you're asking about.  Stack Overflow is not an on-demand code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

First, beware of the gotcha that `getMonth()` returns a value from 0 to 11, not 1 to 12 like you'd expect. Add 1 to that value.

Then you can simplify the logic to check that:

```
inputMonth + inputYear * 12 >= currentMonth + currentYear * 12
```

Comment: the logic is great, help me how to apply logic in this validator plugin

Comment: @Xyaa, you have to at least make an attempt at coding the logic yourself before coming here for help.